# Add point at the end of the graph without redrawing

Tags: swift, highcharts

When we add the point into the graph, it redraw the graph every time. But we want that the new point would be add at the end of the graph without redrawing. Also, when the data is not updating in the graph it must showing the value for after every second and the x-axis of the graph should be update. [Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yor1FZevihXoNB7Ax2ngB4-8NIK-1wf7/view?usp=share_link)

```
import UIKit
import Highcharts
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import Charts

class LiveTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Aitime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nowusdt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nowq8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inusdt: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var live: LineChartView!
@IBOutlet weak var Number: UILabel!
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var number: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        Number.text = "#"+String(number)
        
    }
}

var quantityArray: [Double] = []

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



func LiveChart(quantity: Double,lastQuatityTimestamp: Int, timerIncrease: Int) {
    print("quantity",quantity)
    self.quantityArray.append(quantity)
    
    print("quantityArray",quantityArray)
    
    let chartView = HIChartView(frame: live.bounds)
    
    
    let options = HIOptions()
    
    let chart = HIChart()
    chart.type = "spline"
    chart.marginRight = 10
    
    options.chart = chart
    
    let time = HITime()
    time.useUTC = true
    options.time = time
    
    let title = HITitle()
    title.text = "Live random data"
    options.title = title
    
    let accessibility = HIAccessibility()
    accessibility.announceNewData = HIAnnounceNewData()
    accessibility.announceNewData.enabled = true
    accessibility.announceNewData.minAnnounceInterval = 15000
    accessibility.announceNewData.announcementFormatter = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function (allSeries, newSeries, newPoint) { if (newPoint) { return 'New point added. Value: ' + newPoint.y; } return false; }")
    options.accessibility = accessibility
    
    let xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.type = "datetime"
    xAxis.tickPixelInterval = 150
    options.xAxis = [xAxis]
    
    let yAxis = HIYAxis()
    yAxis.title = HITitle()
    yAxis.title.text = "Value"
    
    let plotLines = HIPlotLines()
    plotLines.value = 0
    plotLines.width = 1
    plotLines.color = HIColor(hexValue: "808080")
    yAxis.plotLines = [plotLines]
    options.yAxis = [yAxis]
    
    let tooltip = HITooltip()
    tooltip.headerFormat = "<b>{series.name}</b><br/>"
    tooltip.pointFormat = "{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}"
    options.tooltip = tooltip
    
    let legend = HILegend()
    legend.enabled = false
    options.legend = legend
    
    let exporting = HIExporting()
    exporting.enabled = false
    options.exporting = exporting
    
    let spline = HISpline()
    spline.name = "Random data"

    spline.data = [
        
        
    ]
    
    for i in 1...timerIncrease {
        spline.data.append(["x": lastQuatityTimestamp-1+i, "y": self.quantityArray[i-1]])
    }
    
    
    options.series = [spline]
    
    chartView.options = options
    
    self.live.addSubview(chartView)
    
    
}

}
```

Comment: In plain JS, it's options to change default redraw fired during [addPoint()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint) method. Check this [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lvtdc4aj/).

Comment: I don't understand in JS. Can you give the swift language reference.

Comment: Try find in `HIPoint Class Reference` --> [update:](https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/Classes/HIPoint.html#//api/name/update:), inside update you can add points, and optionally not redraw series.